# Can we run certain javascript in an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I am new at JavaScript objects and wondering if we could run JavaScript in an Object? This is what I want to do-

```
$('.element').click(function () {
    var data = $(this).attr('data-home');
    if (data !== undefined) {
        var jsRun = {
            a: $('.more').show(),
            b: $('.div').show(),
            c: window.location = "www.url.com",
            d: location.reload()
        };
    }
    return jsRun[data];
});
```

I wrote return jsRun because I'm not quite sure what to do if this is allowed and how to make it run the code that I specified. Any suggestions would help thanks

Comment: Did you try it? I would think a switch / case would be more appropriate.

Comment: @adeneo That wouldn't work as it stands, since the OP wants to conditionally execute *one* of those statements based on the value of `data`

Comment: @Asad - I know it does'nt work, but instead of asking if it works, why not just try it and see what happens ?

Comment: @Adeneo I knew this wouldn't work ;) I did try it in console. And I knew I was missing some stuff such as the answers have provided me :) Thank you though. I'm not a complete newb lol

Comment: Unless you're defining the object somewhere else, and calling methods from an object literal placed elsewhere, I still think a switch / case would be easier.

Comment: please post an answer so I can see what you are speaking of, Remember if I'm new at Objects I'm probably new with the switch/case thank you Adeneo

Comment: I'll just get downvoted, but give me a second and I'll put up an answer.

Comment: You won't be downvoted by me as I would like to see this and become more knowledgeable in JavaScript and understand what you are saying. Anyone downvoting should at least leave an explanation or don't down vote as I am asking Adeneo to add this. Thank you

Comment: @adeneo Probably won't be downvoted, that's what switch case is for after all.

Comment: @Asad should I use switch case instead? What is your opinion?

Comment: @EasyBB I don't see any significant advantages to either approach, unless you're generating your collection of methods dynamically, in which case you can't actually use a switch.

Comment: It depends on the functionality and what you prefer really. An object can be placed anywhere and referenced, while a switch was intended just for this, switching between functions, but can't be moved or changed much.

Comment: The elements that will be clicked are generated dynamically. IF that is what you mean?

Comment: That does'nt really matter, dynamic elements just needs a delegated event handler, the object or switch would be the same.

Comment: @Adeneo yes I will delegate these once everything is in order with the actual functions in object are working correctly :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enclose all of those in functions, after which they can be invoked as methods of the object.

```
$('.element').click(function () {
    var data = $(this).attr('data-home'),
        jsRun; //your variable declaration is hoisted to here anyway
    if (data !== undefined) {
        jsRun = {
            a: function(){
               $('.more').show();
            },
            ...
        };
        return jsRun[data]();
    }
});
```

The result, assuming `data` is "a", is that `$('.more')` is shown. I've moved the invocation inside the conditional block, since I'm assuming you only want this to happen if `data` has a value.

Comment: Thank you, and I'm very surprised that I actually knew to write return at the end LOL! It was my first time actually using return if you can believe that. I am going to try this out before accepting the answer. You did receive an upvote as well as @Dave

Comment: @EasyBB I've made a couple of small changes that you might also want to take into consideration.

Comment: Yes I saw this. I can see the invocation moved to inside the conditional. Though can you please explain line 3 the variable declaration? Is this to become a global or what?

Comment: Also I don't need to place var jsRun = ?

Comment: @EasyBB When you declare a variable anywhere in a scope, JS automatically moves its declaration (but not its assignment) to the top of the scope. So, `function(){alert('hello'); var x = "foo";}` is actually going to behave as `function(){var x; alert('hello'); x="foo";}`. I thought I'd make this more explicit.

Comment: I am getting Unexpected Identifier on this line `return jsRun[hdata]();`

Comment: @EasyBB You did replace the ellipses in my code with your actual options, right?

Comment: Yes Yes lol I forget the line before the `jsRun[hdata]();` I just had `}` and not `};` lets see if that works

Comment: Ok so now it says `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token return `

Comment: Fixed it myself boy I was missing another Curly. Good thing I can debug golly! Though now for some reason these events in the object are not running at all?

Comment: @EasyBB Could you please paste your code into the JS editor [here](http://jsfiddle.net/), click save and give me the link? It is a bit hard to see what the problem is without seeing the code.

Comment: Could I just give you the url of the site html?

Comment: Nevermind! Wow way to many mistakes on my behalf. I set the attribute in the dynamic content but not the hardcoded elements. Thanks it works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Use a switch :

```
$('.element').on('click', function() {
    switch ( $(this).data('home') ) {
       case 'a': $('.more').show();
         break;
       case 'b': $('.div').show();
         break;
       case 'c':  window.location = "www.url.com";
         break;
       case 'd':  location.reload();
         break;
       default:
                  goNuts(); // do something if none of the above 
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh ok thank you for showing me what switch case was. Though as it seems they are the same amount of lines in coding. And same weight overall. I believe I will stick with the Object sense. Unless you have any other reasons on why I should use this and not object? Such as speed of the two. And see you already have two upvotes, ;) no downvoting lol! thank you for working with me and showing me this, I truly appreciate this!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use functions;

```
a: function(){$('more').show();}
```

Then call

```
jsRun[data]();
```

(Note the brackets)

Comment: Another option is to use strings and `eval`, but don't do that. `eval` is dangerous when used wrongly and slower. I only mention it in case you find a suggestion in favour of it elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah I heard that about eval as it is spelled such as evil LOL Someone told me that so I always strayed away from it haha

Answer (score 0):

You are **not** running this code **inside** the object.

You are running it **before** the object creation. Anything that these expressions will return will be set into the keys where you placed the expression.

Be aware that any expression returns something, at least: `undefined`